# Need to export data from cassandra 1.2 for a demo

Tags: syntax, import, cassandra, export, cqlsh

I have to transfer some data from an older cassandra 1.2 instance to a demo instance that has personal information anonymized.

I discovered the COPY command and that seems to work, but I see no option to specify a limit.  I'd like to do something like take one year's worth of data only, however there seems to be no way to specify that.

What I have now is working, but it's dumping the entire contents of the tables, which is way more than I need.

export data

```
COPY my_keyspace.ThingEventLog( key, column1 , value ) to 'ThingEventLog.csv';
```

import data

```
COPY my_keyspace.ThingEventLog( key, column1 , value ) from 'ThingEventLog.csv';
```

Thanks for any other ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not until Cassandra 2.0 and later that the `MAXOUTPUTSIZE` is supported as a `COPY` option. The only data limitation Cassandra 1.2 allows you to specify is by column. While it's more data than you need, at least it reads/spits out data incredibly quickly.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra

Comment: Thank you. Okay.  Exporting one of the tables this way caused cassandra to exceed it's available heap memory and go down hard.  Someone else suggested writing a script using pycassa, so that may be a better way to go.